# Can I use GestureDetectors in Flutter to detect Gesture from the native platform

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I am trying to develop a Flutter app that will keep track of the user interaction with the mobile even if the app is running in the background. For example, if the user tap, drag, ..... or any other gesture. I would like my app to be able to register those gestures when it is active and when it is running in the background and the user is using another app. Is it possible to do this using Flutter?

Comment: I think, you can do with native instead of flutter for this case, because you need to use native framework classes for this case, if you use flutter you want to call method channel to do this progress , i think its not as efficient way for this case..

Comment: Thanks you @NavinKumar, do you know if there is a flutter plugin

Comment: hi! have you figured it out?

Comment: No unfortunately